# UIImageView + UIImage vs CALayer + Content Efficiency

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage

Currently, I have an `UIImageView` that update its `UIImage` every few seconds or so.  This is an endless process in a very heavy UI.

Given that using `CALayers` where ever possible over `UIView`'s are always lighter in weight, I am wondering if I convert the `UIImageView` to `CALayer` and setting `UIImage` to setting content of `CALayer`?

---

Current

```
//Every 2 seconds
myImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: myCGImage)
```

Suggestion

```
//Every 2 seconds
myLayer.content = myCGImage
```

[image]

[image]

---

Since `UIImageView` acts slightly different, I am wondering which method would be more efficient on the CPU/GPU overall.

Comment: I’d question your premise. An image view _is_ a CALayer. The render tree is made of layers. So what difference are you pointing to? If you are having performance problems, use Instruments to measure. If not, just keep on keeping on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `UIView` objects are fairly thin wrappers around `CALayers`. `UIImageView` is no exception to that. Most of the "heavy lifting" of decoding and displaying the image is done by the `CALayer` in both cases, so I doubt if you'll see much difference.

`UIImageView` is easier to use, and the resulting code is easier to read, so unless you need to do something that requires you to use `CALayers`, I'd stick with `UIKit` objects.

Comment: But as Matt says in his comment, if you need to do performance optimizations, use Instruments to identify the bottlenecks.